# How to disable frame rate counter and live visual tree toolbar when debugging UWP?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017. When I run a UWP project by clicking the following button (enclosed by red rectangle),

[image]

I got the following result.

[image]

The number `001 000` hides my text box so it is distracting. How to remove these numbers as well as the tool bar (on the right)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn off the counters in the top left comment out the following line of code or set the proerty to false in app.xaml.cs

```
this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

You can turn off the toolbar in the "live visual tree" tools

http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/06/11/turn-on-off-runtime-in-app-xaml-inspection-toolbar-from-visual-studio/

Comment: `this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;` no longer exists? I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer it still exists, but if you're using Xamarin it will be under the UWP project