# When debugging in Visual Studio 2022, what is the meaning of the white-on-black numbers that are displayed?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When I run my UWP app in debug mode, there are numbers generated at the top left of my Window,

[image: top left of my window]
as well as similar numbers (typically larger, right now it is "060 018") at the top right of my monitor (these top right numbers (but not the top left ones) disappear if you try to do a screen snip).

What is the meaning of these numbers?  They take enough space they must have some use.  Is there any way to suppress them?  The "Enable in-app Toolbar" option allows you to remove the toolbar that is generated in the upper center of your app (go to live visual tree, show in XAML live preview, select element, etc.) but has no effect on these mysterious numbers.

Tried flipping the Enable in-app Toobar option, asking Bing, but neither had any useful effect.

Comment: Maybe the Frame Rate Counter? If yes, similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009704/how-to-disable-frame-rate-counter-and-live-visual-tree-toolbar-when-debugging-uw).

Comment: Maybe the Frame Rate Counter? If yes, similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009704/how-to-disable-frame-rate-counter-and-live-visual-tree-toolbar-when-debugging-uw).

Comment: I think you might be right, thanks.  Just saw this today, had given up on finding an answer.

Good link!